# What is the cause of this discoloration on stucco siding?

Tags: mold, stucco, rot, green, moss

I was wondering what this greenish discoloration is on my stucco. I think it might be water related since there’s some wood rot I’ve felt under that area (a whole other can of worms, I know). I Was wondering if this could be related to the rot since I’ve noticed it on a few other places but not as dark as here.
[image]

Edit: more details: there are studs behind the stucco, They are soft enough for a flathead screw driver to penetrate a half inch through. The wall is hard to the touch mad doesn’t feel wet or spongy

Comment: Are those scratches in it from you trying to brush it away? That could be a repair done at some point in the past that didn't leave a proper surface seal.

Comment: `what is cause ...?` cannot be answered without examining the wall ... only guesses can be made

Comment: @Fredric I made no attempts to brush them away. I can’t speak for the previous owners though

Comment: Is there a stud directly behind that spot or the other stains? Is the wall solid or spongy? Any and every detail you can possibly provide to help people make and informed guess instead of just a random guess will help your cause.